# Sequelize migration dialect error - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

when i use "sequelize db:migrate" command. I got following error!

Sequelize CLI [Node: 8.9.1, CLI: 3.2.0, ORM: 4.29.0]

WARNING: This version of Sequelize CLI is not fully compatible with Sequelize v4. https://github.com/sequelize/cli#sequelize-support

Loaded configuration file "config\config.js".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

my code link --> 
[code github link](https://github.com/iamevenstronger/HoneyBee)

i tried everything i have got! I can't get any solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the github code and tried with diff node versions and its working all good :

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
Sequelize [Node: 9.2.0, CLI: 2.8.0, ORM: 4.29.0]

CLI version 3.9.1
```

---

```
Sequelize [Node: 8.9.1, CLI: 2.8.0, ORM: 4.29.0]

CLI version 3.9.1
```

---

```
Sequelize [Node: 6.11.2, CLI: 2.8.0, ORM: 4.29.0]

CLI version 3.9.1
```

---

The issue is might be with your OS or `npm install --save mysql2` installation.